# Среднее значение разновероятных результатов

Tags: алгоритм, логика

Столкнулся с тем,что не могу выразить на бумаге/консоле формулу, как мне казалось, тривиальной задачи. Допустим, есть событие, которое в 55% имеет значение 1, в 25% - 2, в 20% - 3. Как будет выглядеть формула среднего значения этих разновероятных исходов?

Comment: Средневзвешенной, 1,65

Comment: Есть разные средние, в основном используют: среднее арифметическое, среднее квадратическое, и среднее гармоническое.

Comment: @Mirdin спасибо. тот случай, когда очень лаконичный ответ с последующем гуглением дал результат)

Answer (score 1):

Если *X* -  дискретная случайная величина, имеющая распределение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то из определения интеграла Лебега следует, что

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если говорить об интеграле Лебега, стоит, наверное, упомянуть, что он тут взялся из определения мат. ожидания.

Comment: @VladD Это цитата из Википедии :)